# How can I get Matlab Compiler?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Does it include in a Matlab version or I've to buy or download it by myself?
I've to use it for my Netbeans project.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Type `ver` in Matlab command window. It will output a list of the toolboxes you have installed. Within the list look for:

```
MATLAB Compiler
```

and/or:

```
MATLAB Compiler SDK
```

If it's isn't there, then you don't have it installed and maybe don't have a license for it too, so you have to [purchase one](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html).

Comment: Does it installed at any Matlab version? Now I only have Matlab 7. Am I need to upgrade it?

Comment: I think it was started at Matlab 8, so this toolbox may not be available for your version of Matlab.

Comment: So, Matlab Compiler has been included in Matlab 8 higher. Is that true?

Comment: MATLAB Compiler has existed for a long time, certainly before MATLAB version 7. It has never been included as part of MATLAB, and has always been an add-on product. Be aware that version 7 is very old (7.0 is from 2004, and 7.14 is from 2012) and is no longer fully supported by MathWorks. If you are trying to call MATLAB from Java (you mentioned NetBeans), you'll also need either MATLAB Compiler SDK (recent versions) or MATLAB Builder for Java (old versions such as 7). These are also add-on products.